# Can I get repeater item count in the javascript script method?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have one requirement. I have a repeater in the usercontrol and devexpress button in the parent view. I'm calling clientsideevents from the button like below:

```
    <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnNextStep" runat="server" Text="Proceed to Step 2" AutoPostBack="False" UseSubmitBehavior="False">

                        <clientsideevents click="function(s, e) {
                        { ToggleActive(); } }" />                            


                        <Image Url="~/next.png" />

      </dx:ASPxButton>
```

Now I want to put some check in the ToggleActive() method like if repeater doesn't have any item then it should not goes to next step and show an alert like you don't have any item in the respective repeater. My question is like how to get the total item count in the JavaScript method ToggleActive();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeater renders a `table` element so you can find the `tr` count to find the item count.

Try this.

```
function ToggleActive(){
    //Change the table selector based on your markup that is rendered
    //Here I am using :gt(0) because first row will be header row
    if($("#repeaterId").find('tr:gt(0)').length > 0){
         //Do something
    }
    else{
         alert("You don't have any item");
    }
}
```

Comment: The Repeater only renders a table if you declare it. Not by itself.