# How to get the total count of rows the Asp:Repeater has generated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

As my question suggests , I just need to get the total count of rows that the repeater control has generated using Javascript or JQuery.

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546659/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn basic about the asp.net controls first. As it is basic that,

`Repeater` renders a table element so you can find the `tr` count to find the item count.

```
 function ToggleActive() {
        var rpCount = $('#myTable >tbody >tr').length;
        alert(rpCount);
        if ($("#repeaterId").find('tr:gt(0)').length > 0) {
            alert('some alert text');
        }
        else {
            alert("You don't have any item");
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps to cover your question

Reference took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021510/can-i-get-repeater-item-count-in-the-javascript-script-method)

More about REPEATER control [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Hi @coder . I tried your suggestion, but it takes me to the else part :(

Comment: Found it now though, using this:
var rowCount = $('#myTable >tbody >tr').length;. Thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: did u get the first alert ? or directly to the else part ?

Comment: i got the direct else, now it is working fine with what i had did though :)

Comment: ok., fine no issue. I have also updated my answer. IF possible check now and if it works kindly accept it as an answer for future reference

Comment: That is not correct. A Repeater will only render a table if you declare it. Not by itself.

Comment: Hi Alexandar, i had declared a table in it, so no issues :)